# PowerShell script to alter item security inheritance

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am working on SPE code to set user permissions for a specific tree item.

```
$role = "Michael"
$path = "master:\content\home\distributors\a-b\Austria"
$acl1 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:read -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity $role
$acl2 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:write -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity $role
$acl3 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:rename -PropagationType Descendants -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity $role
$acl3a = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:rename -PropagationType Entity -SecurityPermission DenyAccess -Identity $role
$acl4 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:create -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity $role
$acl5 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:delete -PropagationType Descendants -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity $role
$acl5a = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:delete -PropagationType Entity -SecurityPermission DenyAccess -Identity $role
$acl6 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:read -PropagationType Descendants -SecurityPermission AllowInheritance -Identity $role
Get-Item -Path $path | Add-ItemAcl -AccessRules $acl1, $acl2, $acl3, $acl3a, $acl4, $acl5, $acl5a, $acl6 -PassThru
```

This is working to set the item and descendants for read, write, rename, create, and delete.
I can't figure out how to also set the inheritance option for item and descendants though.

It doesn't seem I can do `item:inheritance` under `-AccessRight`.

When I try doing: `New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:read -PropagationType Descendants -SecurityPermission AllowInheritance -Identity $role` it doesn't do anything.

Any thoughts on this?

[image: assign security rights]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the official docs you should be assigning the output from `New-ItemAcl` to a variable and then using `Set-ItemAcl` to assign to an item; alone it won't change anything on the item.

**Note:** `Add-ItemAcl` works with the existing access controls on the item. `Set-ItemAcl` overwrites with whatever you provide.

From the example [here](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/security/new-itemacl#example-3) you can see the following:

```
$acl1 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:delete -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity "sitecore\adam"
$acl2 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:read -PropagationType Descendants -SecurityPermission DenyAccess -Identity "sitecore\mikey"
Get-Item -Path master:\content\home | Set-ItemAcl -AccessRules $acl1, $acl2 -PassThru
```

Let's say I want to set the inheritance on the item like in the following image:

[image: Example]

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}"

$aclEntity = New-ItemAcl -Identity "sitecore\Developer" -AccessRight "*" -PropagationType Entity -SecurityPermission AllowInheritance
$aclDescendants = New-ItemAcl -Identity "sitecore\Developer" -AccessRight "*" -PropagationType Descendants -SecurityPermission AllowInheritance 
$item | Set-ItemAcl -AccessRules $aclEntity,$aclDescendants -PassThru
```

Combining our two scripts you can achieve this:

[image: Final]

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}"

$role = "sitecore\Developer"

$acl1 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:read -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity $role
$acl2 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:write -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity $role
$acl3 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:rename -PropagationType Descendants -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity $role
$acl3a = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:rename -PropagationType Entity -SecurityPermission DenyAccess -Identity $role
$acl4 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:create -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity $role
$acl5 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:delete -PropagationType Descendants -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity $role
$acl5a = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:delete -PropagationType Entity -SecurityPermission DenyAccess -Identity $role
$acl6 = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:read -PropagationType Descendants -SecurityPermission AllowInheritance -Identity $role

$aclEntity = New-ItemAcl -Identity $role -AccessRight "*" -PropagationType Entity -SecurityPermission AllowInheritance
$aclDescendants = New-ItemAcl -Identity $role -AccessRight "*" -PropagationType Descendants -SecurityPermission AllowInheritance 
$item | Set-ItemAcl -AccessRules $acl1, $acl2, $acl3, $acl3a, $acl4, $acl5, $acl5a, $acl6, $aclEntity, $aclDescendants -PassThru
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! that was a great answer and great description. Thank you for your help.